# Refresh linkedin access token automatically

Tags: php, token, linkedin-api, access-token

I have a PHP application usign LinkedIn API to show my company updates.

I know that the Access token has a duration of 60 days. And to refresh it I need to are connected to linkeIn and have a current Access token with less than 60 days old.

But my question is, in my application, users don't log in it, I use my own account to get the first access token and call API method with my Access Token.

How can I refresh my own access token to my web application works more than 60 days without get a new token manually? If I don't do anything but my app is still calling the API, the access token will be refreshed automatically?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you have to manually login and update the 60 days token.

I have build a similar c#.net app where I save the token and exp.date in a file. I then cache the file for ever.

I cache the result from API for 5min. When cache expires and I make a new request to the API I also check the exp. date of the token.

When it is less then 3 days I send an email to admin to update the token by login in through my special login window where I save the 60 days access token.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 documentation covers how to refresh your access tokens:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#refresh

Note that there is a requirement that the user is logged into linkedin.com in order to refresh their token - so if your app has no user interaction when you attempt to do the refresh, it won't work and the tokens will be expired by LinkedIn.